# Number of solutions of $a^x+b^x=c$: how to simplify?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

Working out the number of solutions for $x\in\Bbb R$ in $$a^x+b^x=c$$ with $a,b,c\in\Bbb R^+$ and $a\neq b$, I found the following: The number of solutions is
$\def\artanh{\operatorname{artanh}}$

$$S(\alpha,\beta) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } |\alpha|>1 \\
1, & \text{if } |\alpha|=1 \text{ and } \beta>-\ln2\\
0, & \text{if } |\alpha|=1 \text{ and } \beta\leqslant -\ln2 \\
0, & \text{if } |\alpha|<1 \text{ and } \beta < g(\alpha) \\
1_2,&\text{if } |\alpha|<1 \text{ and } \beta = g(\alpha) \\
2, & \text{if } |\alpha|<1 \text{ and } \beta > g(\alpha) \\
\end{cases}\tag 1$$
with
$$
\alpha = \frac{\ln(a\cdot b)}{\ln(a/b)}, \qquad
\beta = \ln(c/2) \tag 2
$$
and
$$ g(x) = -\frac12 \ln \left(1 - x^2\right) - x \artanh x \tag 3$$

$1_2$ stands for *"one solution of multiplicity 2"*, and solutions without subscript are of multiplicity 1.

From what I can tell (1) is correct, but it appears to me that it's more complicated than needed, so **I'd like to simplify it; in particular the expressions involving $g(\alpha)$**.
So far I have the following simplifications:

- The relation $\beta\sim-\ln2$ can be simplified to $c\sim 1$ with $\sim\,\in\{>,\leqslant\}$.
- The relation $|\alpha|\sim1$ is $\alpha^2 \sim 1$ which becomes $\ln a\ln b\sim 0$.

But the most complicated is of course $\beta \sim g(\alpha)$, where I get a mess after substituting $\alpha$.

Comment: Are you looking for solutions $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $x\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: For now it's $x\in\Bbb R$, added to the question. My question is not about finding these solutions, though, it's about counting them and simplifying $S(\alpha, \beta)$.

Comment: 1. Yes, you are looking for the amount of solutions. But the domain of $x$ impacts the number of solutions. 2. There is a typo: "soluions". I cannot fix it, as a 1-letter edit is not permitted. 3. interesting question +1.

Comment: Equivalently, you are looking for how many solutions $y^{\log_b(a))}+y=c$ has.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash. Does thak make it any simpler? What's the number of solutions of that one?